# What kind of meat Guan yin believer are allowed to eat?

Tags: kwan-yin

My girlfriend is from a Thai / Chinese familly.
They are buddist and they follow the Guan Yin precepts.

I know they can't eat beef, but this is not the only meat they refuses to eat.

They basicly eat only chicken and pork.

However her mother tried to eat some sheep meat just by curiosity.

I would like to know what kind of meat are you allowed to eat when you follow the Guan Yin precepts and which one are strictly prohibited.

Answer (score 1):

I have only heard that laymen followers of Guan Yin would pursue to not eat the five pungent vegetable such as Onions, Garlic, Scallions, Chives and Leeks. On the meat side, I have only heard that it is just Beef.